# how to disable drag and drop in Jquery Nestable List

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface, jquery-nestable

Im trying to created a nested list using jquery nestable with drag feature disable throughout the list.
Below is my html.

```
<div class="dd" id="nestable">
<ol class="dd-list">
    <li class="dd-item" id="no-drag">
        <div class="dd-handle">
            Foo
            <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                <a class="blue" href="#">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>
                </a>

                <a class="red" href="#">
                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                </a>
            </div>

        </div>
        <ol class="dd-list">
            <li class="dd-item" id="no-drag">
                <div class="dd-handle">
                    Bar
                    <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                        <a class="blue" href="#">
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>
                        </a>

                        <a class="red" href="#">
                            <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <ol class="dd-list">
                    <li class="dd-item" id="no-drag">
                        <div class="dd-handle">
                            Baz
                            <div class="pull-right action-buttons">
                                <a class="blue" href="#">
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-pencil bigger-130"></i>
                                </a>

                                <a class="red" href="#">
                                    <i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o bigger-130"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ol>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ol>
```

My script looks like below::

```
$('.dd').each(function(){
            $(this).nestable({
                maxDepth: 1,
                group: $(this).prop('id')
            });
        });
```

At the moment, im able to create nested list and user can rearrange the nested list. I want that feature to disabled but im not able to do it. Please advise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, and fixed it by using CSS `pointer-events`.

**CSS:**

```
.drag_disabled{
    pointer-events: none;
}

.drag_enabled{
    pointer-events: all;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<label class=""><input id="draggable_list" class="" name="draggable_list" type="checkbox" value="false"> <span>Activate Ordering </span></label>

<div id="list" class="drag_disabled dd">
    <ol class="dd-list">
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="Item 1">
            <div class="dd-handle dd-outline dd-anim">
                Text 1
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li class="dd-item" data-id="Item 3">
            <div class="dd-handle dd-outline dd-anim">
                Text 2
            </div>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

**JavaScript** (just toggle classes `drag_enabled` and `drag_disabled` on checkbox:

```
$('#list').nestable({maxDepth: 1});

     $('#draggable_list').change(function(){
         $('#list').toggleClass('drag_disabled drag_enabled');
     });
```

Comment: This will break the expand/collapse of the nestable list if the list has nested elements

Comment: @MohamedSanaulla is correct but you can simply re-enable those actions like this `[data-action="collapse"] {pointer-events: all;}`

Answer (score 5):

I have gone through the js file and I strike that the drag-drop handling with class "dd-handle".

So if you change the handle class name then it will work like charm.

```
        $('.nestable').nestable({handleClass:'123'});
```

Done

Answer (score 1):

You can set maxDepth: 0
This will not disable drag and drop, but do not prevent the obj relocation

Comment: Setting maxDepth to zero does not actually prevent the obj relocation. It prevents re-location object from parent to the child state. However, re-locating from child to parent is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. You just need to add these css codes

```
.drag_disabled{
      pointer-events: none;
  }
  .drag_enabled{
      pointer-events: all;
  }
  .dd-expand{
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
  .dd-collapse{
    pointer-events: auto;
  }
```

And you add the javascript in footer

```
$('#nestable02').nestable({maxDepth: 1});
```

You disable all pointer-events excepted the collapse.